# Asp.Net Core 1.0 and SonarQube analysis

Tags: sonarqube, tfs-2015, asp.net-core-1.0

TFS 2015 Update 2.1
Asp.Net Core 1.0
SonarQube 5.6
C# Plugin: 5.3

I would like to know if Asp.Net Core 1.0 and SonarQube analysis will as it is or we need to do something else too?

For now, my build is successful but i am not getting any data on my dashboard.

Am i missing anything?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-167) workitem. Microsoft will change the project structure again, dropping the json configuration file. Maybe that will give some delay.

Comment: Hello Jeroen
Thanks for your reply. You mean 
* xproj extension is not supported by SonarQube?
* No Support for Asp.Net ?
* When this will be available?

Comment: I mean Asp.Net core,

It would be great if i can get above information as it will help me to answer top management